# plot $D=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: z\ge 0 , z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis

For plot this domain can I use polar coordinates in space? Is it a solid of rotation?

I want to prove existence of this integral on $D$:

$\int \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1) e^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,e^{-z^2}}{x^2+y^2} dx\, dy\, dz\,$.

If I use cylindrical coordinates I consider $D'=\{(r,\theta,z): 0\le z\le \frac{1}{r},r\ge0, \theta \in [0,2\pi] \}$

Comment: I guess for this question you can use the *cylindrical* coordinates in the space, which is effectively the same as switching the $(x,y)$ coordinates to polar and keeping $z$ unchanged.